# Cómo generar una fecha aleatoria entre 2 rangos en Java

Tags: java-8

necesito generar una fecha aleatoria basados en 2 fechas (Date)
basicamente se me habia ocurrido generar numeros aleatorios y hacer if anidados que esten entre los rangos de las fechas pero se me hacia muy tedioso tener que hacer tantos if's para este tipo de problema

muchas gracias

Comment: bienvenido, por favor lee [ask] y mejora tu publicación agrega lo que haz tratado o investigado, la comunidad no es para llegar y pedir que se te haga algo

Comment: Hola Ana, he puesto en espera tu pregunta porque has de mostrar más informacion: lo que has intentado, qué problemas concretos has tenido, la investigacion realizada para intentar resolver esos problemas... mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom; 

ThreadLocalRandom r =ThreadLocalRandom.current();
Date rnd = new Date(r.nextLong(fechaInicio.getTime(), fechaFin.getTime());
```

Comment: favor de no responder preguntas que no muestran avance alguno, tampoco dejan claro que dudas tienen, ayudanos a ma ntener la calidad del sitio, además es de baja calidad solo poner código por que ni explicas que hace ese script -1

Comment: mucha gracias tu codigo funciona perfectamente para lo que necesito